# Android SQLiteException during creating Table

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-studio

I am getting this error again and again.Can't figure it out how to solve.I am sharing the codes.Please help!

Codes:
addnewcontact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sambal.contactmanager.AddNewContact">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mobile Number:"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email Id:"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etMobileNumber"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etEmail"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is DataBaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.sambal.contactmanager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="contacts";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER,E-MAIL TEXT)");



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);


    }
    public boolean insertData(String name,int mobile_number,String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();



            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("NAME", name);
            contentValues.put("MOBILE_NUMBER", mobile_number);
            contentValues.put("E-MAIL", email);

            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            if (result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;

        }

    }
```

AddNewContact.java

```
package com.example.sambal.contactmanager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddNewContact extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,mobile_number,email;
    Button save;

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_contact);

        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        mobile_number= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMobileNumber);
        email= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        save= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    boolean result = databaseHelper.insertData(name.getText().toString(),
                            Integer.parseInt(mobile_number.getText().toString()), email.getText().toString());
                    if (result)
                        Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(AddNewContact.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sambal.contactmanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    Button addcontact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addcontact= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
         addcontact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddNewContact.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
    }
}
```

The logcat

```
 03-30 23:11:27.650 28750-28750/com.example.sambal.contactmanager E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error
03-30 23:11:27.673 28750-28750/com.example.sambal.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.sambal.contactmanager, PID: 28750
                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER,E-MAIL TEXT)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:25)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:40)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.AddNewContact$1.onClick(AddNewContact.java:33)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4790)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19883)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
03-30 23:11:54.392 29707-29707/com.example.sambal.contactmanager E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error
03-30 23:11:54.397 29707-29707/com.example.sambal.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.sambal.contactmanager, PID: 29707
                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEcontacts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEcontacts (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER,E-MAIL TEXT)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:25)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:40)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.AddNewContact$1.onClick(AddNewContact.java:33)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4790)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19883)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
03-30 23:12:08.363 30145-30145/com.example.sambal.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.sambal.contactmanager, PID: 30145
                                                                                   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "fhh"
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                       at com.example.sambal.contactmanager.AddNewContact$1.onClick(AddNewContact.java:34)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4790)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19883)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a space between Table keyword and Table Name:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,MOBILE_NUMBER INTEGER,E-MAIL TEXT)");
```

Here is an example:

```
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + TITLE
      + " text not null, " + BODY + " text not null " + ");";

  db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: @SAMBAL SRIVASTAVA welcome to stack overflow!! your should mark the answer as correct if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is 
"Create table(space here)table name..."
While see your logcat, see the query, you are missing space between TABLE and CONTACTS.

It's better to use " create table if not exists"